# Orchard CMS - How to use html.action on views of admin pages? Common view for more admin pages

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I need to use one common view(custom extends form needed for administration all my widgets) for more admin pages(EditorTemplates/Parts) of Orchard CMS.
So I tried @Html.Action with err:

*The controller for path '/Alanis.Orchard/Admin/Widgets/EditWidget/5' was not found or does not implement IController.*

Than tried prepare some helper to App_Code, but not found problem.

What is the best practicies to use one view for common code in more admin pages?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to specify the area. Add an area parameter, with the name of the module as the area name.

Comment: I dont use Area here, Controller is in /Controllers/.

Comment: You mean you wrote code under a /controller folder right under the application root, instead of within a module? Well, that can't work.

Comment: No, sry for my explanation, Its in Module.. I use this controller for more things (ajax mb, even Html.Action on no admin views), for those is ok. But, if I want to use them with Html.Action on admin pages, dont work. Exist any module where it works? To inspire.

Comment: Modules *are* areas. Really, add an area parameter, with the name of the module as the area name.

Comment: I dont know why I overlooked it. On no admin pages I use it with area. Stupid mistake. Thanks a lot Bertrand.